# Merge conflict though file was not changed

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge-conflict

We have a feature branch which unfortunately already lives quite a long time. From time to time `develop` is merged into this branch. So far this didn't cause any unexpected conflicts. Today we tried again to merge `develop` into the feature branch (`git merge --ff develop`). Unfortunately git reports a hell of a lot of merge conflicts. As far as we can tell most if not all of these conflicts are for files which were not touched in the feature branch itself. If they were modified in the feature branch then only due to these changes being merged in from develop.

We tried to figure out what is happening but could not succeed. Executing

```
git merge-base --all develop HEAD
```

in the feature branch outputs a single commit `abcdef`. `HEAD~2` is a merge commit merging `123456` and `abcdef`. Commit `abcdef` is also present in `develop` while `123456` is unique to the feature branch.

How can we figure out what is causing these merge conflicts in order to avoid them? Manually merging all these files would be a huge mess.

Comment: can you post the log of the both the branch? git log --oneline (for both the branches)

Comment: Or a screenshot from `gitk --all`

Comment: @SamuelRobert The whole logs are *very* huge. Starting from which point should I post them? Is there an easy way to anonymize them?

Comment: Just wanted to check if the history of both the branches are consistent..

Comment: @SamuelRobert I appreciate it! However, there are more than ten thousand commits. Not sure if all of them are relevant?

Comment: Did anyone merge into develop using `-s ours` strategy? We've experienced that such a merge, which essentially should disregard changes from the source branch, suddenly resurfaces as a merge conflict when we merge this further. In other words, merge from X into develop, disregarding changes from X because we know there will be merge conflicts but we want to record a merge as happened. Then we merge develop into Y and suddenly all those merge conflict resurfaces. Could this have happened here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can't tell because too many people are involved. How could I figure it out?

Comment: @sigy How many commits since last successful merge?

Comment: @SamuelRobert In develop 300, in our feature branch 1 commit since the merge I named `abcdef` in my question.